Add an underscore after numbers in Notepad++
I have a scenario where I have list with some numbers in Notepad++. Here is the sample text:
1-This is item one
2_This is item two
3This is item three
4_This is item five
5This is item six
6 This is item seven

I want to put an underscore after the numbers so the output is like:
1_This is item one
2_This is item two
3_This is item three
4_This is item five
5_This is item six
6_This is item seven

Here is the code which I have written (\d+)(?!_).(.+?) and replace \1_\2
It is deleting the first character of point 3 and 5, "T" in this case.

grep is only used to find, not to replace. Please, review your tags. I guess you are talking about Adobe-Indesing, aren't you? What are “n-space” and “m-space”?

Yes you are right. I use grep mostly in Adobe's InDesign. Sometimes, I copy paste the data in Notepad++, use regex and the copy back to InDesign.
In InDesign n-space's width is lesser than m-space's width. If I talk specifically about n-space, in InDesign it is denoted by ~> (unicode \u2002). For m-space unicode is \u2003. \h matches all the spaces, be it n or m or thin or normal space.
In Indesign replace is like substitution in Notepad++ or regex101.

How about: Find: (\x{602}\d+)(?!~>)\h*(?=[Range of characters you want]) and Replace: $1~> ?

Please, don't put example in comments (it could be deleted!), edit your question and add sample text (not an image) and expected result. I don't understand why you're talking about spaces in the question and, now, you have hyphens and underscores.

Actually n-spaces and m-spaces are not available in other programs so I put and English example with dashes and underscore.

Please also add the application you are running this in into the question body. Regex is not standardized, and so the application you're doing this in is relevant and required information in order to help you.


Ctrl+H
Find what: \d+\K[^a-z]*
Replace with: _
UNTICK Match case
TICK Wrap around
SELECT Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:
\d+         # 1 or more digits
\K          # forget them
[^a-z]*     # 0 or more any character that is not a letter

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):


It worked like a charm.

@Shahid: You're welcome, glad it helps.
